# jQuery - Toggle attributes on two divs on click

Tags: jquery

I am using the `hidden` attribute to show/hide the `.block` div for each `.item`. The problem is I want to only ever show one of the blocks at a time.

How do I update the code so that if one block is showing and the other is toggled, hide the block that was showing?

```js
//hide the blocks
$(".block").attr("hidden", "hidden");

$(".item").each(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
    block = $this.find(".block");

  //Show / hide the blocks
  $this.click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();

    block.attr("hidden") ?
      block.removeAttr("hidden") :
      block.attr("hidden", "hidden");

  });
});
```

```css
.item {
  display: flex;
}

.block {
  border: 2px solid;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <button>Toggle</button>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <button>Toggle</button>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First `.hide()` any `.item div` to hide any that may currently be open, then `.show()` the one that's the sibling of the clicked button:

```js
$('.item div').hide();
$(".item button").on('click', function() {
  // Hide the other block
  $('.item div').hide();
  // Show this block
  $(this).next().show();
});
```

```css
.item {
  display: flex;
}

.block {
  border: 2px solid;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <button>Toggle</button>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <button>Toggle</button>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```